# Hibernate Native Query problem with named parameters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have a problem with Hibernate Native Query. I have one SELECT that selects array slice (PostgreSQL database).

The problem is that hibernate recognizes the following part: ":300" from "SELECT my_array[1:300]..." as named parameter and I get the following exception: Not all named parameters have been set.

I tried to escape the colon (:) with ':' , '::' but with no success.

The Hibernate version is 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use PostgreSQL but if you don't find a proper solution for this problem you can implement an interceptor (extend EmptyInterceptor) and modify your query on `onPrepareStatement(String sql)`.

Which means that you could be using something like `my_array[1|300]` and rewriting it as `my_array[1:300]` to workaround the named parameters problem.

**Edit**: I'm not 100% sure the above works (rewriting native SQL and whether the query parser would allow the special character). I've only done the above in HQL and criteria where I was passing the index hint as a query comment.

Answer (score 3):

The colon is not escapeable in Hibernate itself (known [Bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1237) since 2005).

Answer (score 1):

```
create function array_slice(a anyarray, start int4, end int4) returns anyarray as   
$$
    SELECT a[start:end];
$$
language(sql);
```

Now call this function instead. Did not try it but it will work somehow like this.