# Escaping colons in hibernate createSQLQuery

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, escaping

I am confused on how I can create an SQL statement containing colons.  I am trying to create a view and I am using (notice the double colons):

```
create view MyView as (
  SELECT 
    tableA.colA as colA,
    tableB.colB as colB, 
    round(tableB.colD / 1024)::numeric, 2) as calcValue,
  FROM 
    tableA, tableB
  WHERE
    tableA.colC = 'someValue'
);
```

This is a postgres query and I am forced to use the double colons (::) in order to correctly run the statement.

I then pass the above statement through:

```
s.createSQLQuery(myQuery).executeUpdate();
```

and I get a:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.DataException: \
    could not execute native bulk manipulation query
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(\
    SQLStateConverter.java:102)
    ... more stacktrace...
```

with an output of my above statement changed as (notice the question mark):

```
create view MyView as (
  SELECT 
    tableA.colA as colA,
    tableB.colB as colB, 
    round(tableB.colD / 1024)?, 2) as calcValue,
  FROM 
    tableA, tableB
  WHERE
    tableA.colC = 'someValue'
);
```

Obviously, hibernate confuses my colons with named parameters.

Is there a way to escape the colons (a google suggestion that mentions that a single colon is escaped as a double colon does NOT work) or another way of running this statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `executeUpdate()` method is not intended for DDL statments as `CREATE VIEW` but for DML statements as `UPDATE`

you should instead acquire a plain JDBC connection, may be from the `Session` with `s.connection()` and run your SQL statement.

```
Connection connection = s.connection();
Statment statment = connection .createStatement();
try {
statment .execute("CREATE VIEW ...");
} finally {
 statment .close();
}
```

Comment: I guess that would do.  

But is there NO way to actually parse the colons (if I was stubborn enough and wanted to use the initial way?)

Comment: @Stratosgear You can work around it by using the SQL-standard `CAST` syntax, eg `CAST( round(tableB.colD / 1024) AS numeric )`

Answer (score 0):

See [Hibernate Native Query problem with named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794972/hibernate-native-query-problem-with-named-parameters) for solution.