# Using Hibernate query : colon gets treated as parameter / escaping colon

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, postgresql, hql

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
            createQuery("FROM Weather WHERE city_id = :id AND date " +
                    "BETWEEN now()::date AND now()::date + (:days - 1)").
                    setInteger("id", city_id).setString("days", days).list();
```

getting error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: :
```

How can I use this syntax in HQL?

Basically the problem is that I want to use colon(:) in my query, but when hibernate sees colon, it thinks that it is a paramter(:parameterName is syntax for parameters in HQL), as you can see from my 2 uses(`:id and :days`).

But when I am using now()::date statement, it is specific postgreSQL syntax, hibernate ruins everything.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? cast ?

Comment: No .. just wanna use my SQL query, but Hibernate marks it as invalid.

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2794972/106261

Comment: Sorry, but you can't use SQL in place of HQL. You have supplied an SQL query. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html and try and write your query using valid HQL. Or use a native query.

Comment: @James : Isn't `createSQLQuery` used for native queries? I tried that but now getting a little different error : `Not all named parameters have been set: [:date]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're on Postgres, I would change the date() completely:

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
        createQuery("FROM Weather WHERE city_id = :id AND date " +
                "BETWEEN current_date AND (current_date + (integer :days - 1))").
                setInteger("id", city_id).setString("days", days).list();
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Maybe try using CAST instead of ::.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791325/how-do-i-write-hql-query-with-cast

Answer (score 45):

I just had this problem, had to use casts, so I tried some stuff to make it work.  Turns out you escape : in hibernate with `\`

However, in java, to print `\` to begin with, you have to escape it with `\`.
So, if you want to put a `:` in your SQL hibernate query, you have to write it like: `\\:`

And if you wanted to cast in PostgreSQL, such as in my case, you would have to, for example: `field\\:\\:int` if you wanted to cast some field as an integer.

Comment: This did not work for me with hibernate `3.6.10`. I ended up using `cast(field as integer)` instead.

Comment: It worked for me on hibernate `4.3.11.Final` `sb.append("        NULL\\:\\:DATE              AS date, ");`

Comment: Worked for me too with  `version: '5.0.12.Final'`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createcast.html

Try using cast. To me it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
        createQuery("FROM Weather WHERE city_id = :id AND date " +
                "BETWEEN cast(now() as date) AND cast(now() as date) + (:days - 1)").
                setInteger("id", city_id).setString("days", days).list();
```

Comment: Looks ok to me but please add some comments as to what was wrong :)

Comment: SQL ANSI don't describe casts with double collons. Tô solve this, use cast function, instead.

Answer (score -1):

Named parameters take a colon ':' like [this](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter#Named_Parameters_%3aname_) Is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: Nope...this is actually the problem. I am just trying to use colons in my query, but hibernate thinks that they are parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You escape `:` with `::`. I think.

Or try a [nativequery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/query_native.html#d0e4753)