# Hibernate error while update

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Hibernate query : colon gets treated as parameter / escaping colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475876/using-hibernate-query-colon-gets-treated-as-parameter-escaping-colon)

We are trying to write a native query. When we try to update a particular column value that contains a `": "` ,we get an  exception.

This is the generated query

```
  UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DESCRIPTION = "Test 01 : ABC",LAST_UPDATE_TS =
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,LAST_UPDATE_USER_ID = 111 WHERE MY_ID =123
```

I think the problem lies in the DESCRIPTION data, which contains `': '`

We get this error

```
 nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException:Space is not allowed after 
 parameter prefix ':' ' UPDATE 
 MY_TABLE SET DESCRIPTION = "MY Test 01 : ABC",LAST_UPDATE_TS =
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LAST_UPDATE_USER_ID = 111 WHERE MY_ID =123'
```

This is the Java code that is responsible for the query :

```
 StringBuffer strQry = new StringBuffer(" UPDATE MY_TABLE SET ");

          if(myForm.getDescription() != null){
                 if(flag == 1){
                       strQry.append(",");
                 }
                 strQry.append(" DESCRIPTION = \"" + myForm.getDescription().trim()+ "\" ");
                 flag = 1;
```

Any idea why this error is occurring and how we can get around it ?

Comment: You may want to escape `:` so that it looks like `\\:`

Comment: the data containing ':' is in myForm.getDescription(). Are you saying the we need to edit this data ?

Comment: Yes. Use `replaceAll` for String

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DESCRIPTION = "Test 01 \\: ABC",LAST_UPDATE_TS =
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,LAST_UPDATE_USER_ID = 111 WHERE MY_ID =123
```

add forward slashes.

The colon is used to specify named parameters so you have to escape it(and then escape the escape).

Comment: Err It doesn't even compile in java with single forward slash

Answer (score 0):

You need to parameterize your sql. ":" is a special character that hibernate uses to detect named parameters. So, hibernate throws an exception when trying to parse your query.
You could parameterize your sql shown below.

```
   StringBuffer strQry = new StringBuffer(" UPDATE MY_TABLE SET ");

          if(myForm.getDescription() != null){
                 if(flag == 1){
                       strQry.append(",");
                 }
                 strQry.append(" DESCRIPTION = :description");
                 flag = 1;
....

   if(myForm.getDescription() != null){
        session.setString("description", description)
   }
```

Parameterizing your query is important for two other reasons -

1. Avoid sql injections.
2. Performance gains because of pre-compilation of your sql.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in you case occurs because Hibernate thinks that you are using named parameter (symbol ":" is a special keyword used for this). Try to define description, last_update_user_id and my_id as named parameter for your query. So your code will look like:

```
String queryText = "UPDATE MY_TABLE SET DESCRIPTION = :description,LAST_UPDATE_TS =
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LAST_UPDATE_USER_ID = :lastUpdateUserID WHERE MY_ID = :myId";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryText);
query.setParameter("description", yourDescription);
query.setParameter("lastUpdateUserID", yourLastUpdateUserID);
query.setParameter("myId", yourMyId);
...
```

In my example I define whole query in one place, but you may build it by parts like in your code snippet:

```
 StringBuffer strQry = new StringBuffer(" UPDATE MY_TABLE SET ");

 if(myForm.getDescription() != null){
     if(flag == 1){
           strQry.append(",");
     }
     strQry.append(" DESCRIPTION = :description ");
     flag = 1;
 } 
...
```

EDIT

In you conditions may be even better to use numeric parameters (?1) in query. Example:

```
 List<Object> parametersList = new LinkedList<Object>();
 int parameterPosition = 1;

 StringBuffer strQry = new StringBuffer(" UPDATE MY_TABLE SET ");

 if(myForm.getDescription() != null){
     if(parameterPosition > 1){
           strQry.append(",");
     }
     strQry.append(" DESCRIPTION = ?");
     strQry.append(parameterPosition);
     strQry.append(" ");

     parametersList.add(myForm.getDescription().trim());
     parameterPosition ++;
 } 
...

int position = 1;
for (Object parameter: parametersList) {
     query.setParameter(position, parameter);
     position++;
}
```

An least somehow like this).