# Hibernate 4 escape colon character in createSQLQuery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, escaping

The following hibernate query fails:

`select 1 as "{jsonprop:'string'}" from dual`

with the following exception:

`org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [  select 1 as "{json:'string'}" from dual]`

Is there no way to escape the colon character in Hibernate 4?  Ive tried \: and :: but neither worked.  Ive seen mention that this might have been corrected in the v3 parser, but its still failing - even though the colon is *inside* a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a quick way to test this, but I believe '\:' is what you need.

```
select 1 as "{jsonprop\\:'string'}" from dual
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11971764/3684299

If that doesn't work, where are you defining your query: in a named query file or within a String in code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hibernate 5+ i believe you can use '::' to escape ':'. [see here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1237)

If you're using 4.x a solution i've used is to use like/ilike and the '_' character.