# No value specified for parameter 1 Exception when creating a stored procedure in Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure dynamically from Java, below:

```
String dnyCursorProcedure ="CREATE PROCEDURE dyn_cursor" +
    mNumber + " (IN `query` TEXT, IN `timeout` TINYINT UNSIGNED, OUT x TEXT)"
//more procedure
queryTest = mEntityManager.createNativeQuery(dnyCursorProcedure);
queryTest.executeUpdate();
```

When this piece of code is executed, it gives the "No value specified for parameter 1 Exception ", even when this is a create procedure statement.

What am I missing here?

Edit 1:
Here is the entire procedure.

```
String dnyCursorProcedure ="CREATE PROCEDURE dyn_cursor"
                        +mNumber+" (IN `query` TEXT, IN `timeout` TINYINT UNSIGNED, OUT x TEXT)"
                                        +" BEGIN"
                                        +"  DECLARE val TEXT;"
                                        +"  DECLARE eof BOOL;"
                                        +"  DECLARE cur_dyn"+mNumber+" CURSOR FOR"
                                        +"      SELECT * FROM dyn_view"+mNumber+" ;"
                                        +"  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER"
                                        +"      FOR NOT FOUND"
                                        +"      SET eof = TRUE;"
                                        +"  CALL dyn_lock"+mNumber+" (query, 'dyn_view"+mNumber+"', timeout);"
                                        +"  OPEN cur_dyn"+mNumber+" ;"
                                        +"  DO RELEASE_LOCK('dyn_view"+mNumber+"');"
                                        +"  lp_dyn:LOOP"
                                        +"      IF eof = TRUE THEN"
                                        +"          LEAVE lp_dyn;"
                                        +"      END IF;"
                                        +"      FETCH cur_dyn"+mNumber+" INTO val;"
                                        +"  END LOOP;"
                                        +"  CLOSE cur_dyn"+mNumber+" ;"
                                        +"  SET x = val;"
                                        +" END;";
```

Comment: In error stack find the line number that caused the exception. Check if it is the same as you think. Else, post other part of the code as well.

Comment: @RavinderReddy I checked the stack trace and the exception is at queryTest.executeUpdate(), as expected, I have posted the entire procedure.

Comment: Okay, so i get that hibernate is treating ":LOOP" as a parameter at looking for its value, now I am looking for an escape character.

Comment: even after an hour long effort to find a escape character, I have no solution, is it even possible?

Comment: I refered to the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794972/hibernate-native-query-problem-with-named-parameters) but still i get the same error.